# cpanm use custom libs and cflags

Tags: perl, cpan, xml-libxml, cpanm

On my mac OS X machine `Darwin maci 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0`

I have installed libxml2 and libxslt in following custom directory

`/usr/local/MyLibs/libxml2-2.9.2`

and libxslt

`/usr/local/MyLibs/libxslt-1.1.29`

Now I want to use these libs to build my CPANM module [XML::LibXSLT](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-LibXSLT).

[This](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm#OPTIONS) tells me that I can do so using `--configure-args` (its still experimental). So I do something like,

```
cpanm http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/S/SH/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.94.tar.gz --configure-args="--cflags=-I/usr/local/libxslt-1.1.29/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/MyLibs/libxml2-2.9.2/include/libxml2 --libs=-L/usr/local/libxslt-1.1.29/lib -lxslt -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -licucore -lm -L/usr/local/MyLibs/libxml2-2.9.2/lib -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -liconv -lm" --force
```

However, the build log says that it did not use the libraries installed in my custom location.

Is there something that I am not doing correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the distro's [README](https://github.com/shlomif/perl-XML-LibXSLT/blob/493fba3f854b20d74a3c081492f185aaec7b4f3b/README#L27),

> The Makefile.PL tries to determine the correct compiler and linker
> flags for its library dependencies using pkg-config and
> xslt-config. If this fails, you may override the values like this

> ```
> perl Makefile.PL INC="..." LIBS="..."
> ```

> where INC contains flags for the compiler (such as -I/some_path/include etc.) and LIBS contains linker flags (such as -L/some_path/lib -llibsomething ...).

It might be simpler to forgo `cpanm` and install the module yourself.

```
curl -L -o - http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/S/SH/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXSLT-1.95.tar.gz | tar xz
cd XML-LibXSLT-1.95
perl Makefile.PL INC="..." LIBS="..."
make test
make install
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you were missing quotes around the `--cflags` argument (needed in order to group multiple space-separated arguments together):

```
--configure-args="--cflags='-I/usr/local/libxslt-1.1.29/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/MyLibs/libxml2-2.9.2/include/libxml2'"
```

However `--cflags` and `--libs` are just examples from the cpanm documentation, and might not even be recognized by a distribution's Makefile.PL. As the other answer points out, the arguments to use for XML::LibXSLT are `INC="…"` and `LIBS="…"`; I think providing those to cpanm's `--configure-args` should work:

```
cpanm --configure-args="INC='…' LIBS='…'"
```